# The Great India Rope Trick, Is this possible physically?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

The Great India Rope Trick, Is this possible physically? I think it is impossible, but why can a magician be done.

[Magician Muthukad - The Great India Rope Trick](https://youtu.be/QfDX-a7MQPM)

Comment: It's *magic*: a human trick, using sleight of hand, illusionism, misdirection etc etc. to deceive the audience. If you have money to spare you can buy the secret and perform the trick yourself (and get paid for it too!)

Comment: The key word is "trick"

Comment: @Gert How is this trick possible?

Comment: With the dismemberment and everything?

Comment: @enbin If I knew I would not tell you. Great magic tricks are great secrets!

Answer (score 2):

Magic tricks are primarily about deception and misdirection. What you think is happening may not necessarily be happening.
One explanation in the comments goes as follows:

> The assistant fixing the basket (while audience are focused on the
> main actor) removed a cover from the ground then carefully fixed where
> a pipe clad with rope will comes out.

To actually answer your question, a simplified analogy to the supposed "rope" can be an inverted pendulum, where the end is above the fulcrum. Unless you orient it so that the pendulum is pointing *exactly* straight up with zero error, it will tip to one side, however slowly. As it tips to one side, its acceleration will increase. The rope can be thought of as many of these inverted pendulums stacked on top of each other. It's effectively impossible to keep a rope like this from falling down.

Comment: Do you think there is a tunnel underground in which people are hiding and manipulating ropes?

Comment: Maybe. There might be another way they could've done it.